# How to create error vector without NULLs/NAs?

Tags: r, vector, error-handling

I have a function that starts with input validation.
It checks if the first argument is dataframe, the second is string etc...

I have defined an error vector:

```
err_msg <- c()
```

If any of the validation conditions fails (if's) I am appending the err_msg vector:

```
err_msg[1] <- "Please provide non empty data set!"
err_msg[3] <- "'Product' should be a string" etc...
```

Final error vector looks like this:

```
err_msg
"Please provide non empty data set!", NA, "'Product' should be a string"
```

I want it to omit NA/NULL and shrink it to contain only error messages.

Please advise how can I do it (one line code) maybe there is a function or best practice to do this.

Comment: `na.omit(err_msg)`

Comment: @RonakShah I am aware of na.omit, is there a way to build it without NAs on the fly? I mean without the need to omit or this is the only simple way to do this?

Comment: Why do you assign to an index? Just use `err_msg <- c(err_msg, ...)`. Also, are you aware of existing infrastructure such as `stop` and `stopifnot`?

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible. If you do `vec[1] = "A"; vec[3] = "B";`,  `vec[2]` is going to be `NA`. You can follow @Roland's suggestion which is more appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: @Roland sure I do, the issue is that I am checking with 9 if statements the validity of the inputs. In case I enter one of the if's I am updating the next position in my vector with appropriate error message.
Afterwards IT team will take my vector, and will convert it to log messages.
Hope now you understand the whole picture.

Comment: In my code, if one input checks fails, I stop and throw an error. It does not often make sense to continue checking if one check has failed.

Comment: @RonakShah the main idea here is that I build up my error vector.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments I have changed the error mechanism of my functions and I will not "collect" error messages (I wanted to show all the issues with the inputs in one list/vector for the user to fix all at once).

If there is an error, I have a flag that will become true, the main function code will check the flag and enter the function main code only if it passed validation.

Else print error message.

If next run won't pass validation it will print the appropriate error.
If you think there is another best practice please post here.